# Which platform is better Calibre or Kindle?

Tags: ebook-management

Which platform is better between calibre and kindle

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Calibre is a book management program and Kindles are ereaders.

Answer (score 4):

Calbre is free desktop software for managing digital libraries, and includes an ebook reader, ebook editor, conversion tools, and the ability to communicate with an ebook reader or other device over USB.

Kindle is Amazon's ebook/audiobook platform with desktop and mobile apps.

Both can be used for storing and reading ebooks, but usually they are used together (or Calibre with some other kind of ebook reader).

- Library Management: Calibre
- Ebook reading: Kindle (hardware or app)